# How to extract the last output from the Maximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Pitty on me! Still a beginner. After using Mathematica for 8 years and spending an hour on google, I remained unsuccessful to find an answer of:

How to extract the last element of the output of Maximize function.

```
Maximize[{x^0.5 - 2*y^3 , 0 < x < 1 , 0 < y < 1}, {x, y}]
```

which outputs

```
{1., {x -> 1., y -> 0.000023912}}
```

I need to extract the value of `y` only.

I used `Last@%` but that results in `{x -> 1., y -> 0.000023912}`. Performed random hit and trial methods to access the variable and do it myself but no success. Sigh!

Thank you.

Comment: try `nm = Maximize[{x^0.5 - 2*y^3, 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1}, {x, y}];y /. Last[nm]` or 
`y /. nm[[-1]]` or `nm[[-1, -1, -1]]`?

Comment: Last[nm] results not what I asked for. 
y/.nm[[-1]] too does the same.
nm[[-1,-1,-1]] works but it outputs y-> 0.00023. 
I need only 0.00023.

Comment: kaka, maybe it is version/OS -related  issue. In version 9.1 (windows 10) and in version 12.0.0 (wolfram Cloud) you can use `y /. Last[nm] ` or  `y/. nm[[-1, -1]] ` or `nm[[-1, -1, -1]] ` to get `0.000023912`

Comment: How about this `ArgMax[{x^0.5 - 2 y^3, 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1}, {x, y}] // Last`

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers in @kglr's comment work:

```
nm = Maximize[{x^0.5 - 2*y^3, 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1}, {x, y}];
y /. Last[nm]
y /. nm[[-1]]
nm[[-1, -1, -1]]
(* 0.000023912 *)
(* 0.000023912 *)
(* 0.000023912 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can pick out the value. Here is one neat way that uses the function Last and the function Nest.

```
Nest[Last, Maximize[{x^0.5 - 2*y^3, 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1}, {x, y}], 3]
```

This is another way:

```
Nest[Last, Flatten@Take[Maximize[{x^0.5 - 2*y^3, 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1}, {x, y}], -1], 2]
```